# Permission denied for cvs server via ssh

Tags: permissions, cvs

I cant create a new project by importing a java project via eclipse onto my cvs server via internet.

I created a directory as root called /priv/cvs/.
Then i called "cvs -d /priv/cvs/ init".
I created a user named cvs and a groups called cvs.
The repository is owned by cvs and in group cvs.

Then i created a user "ben" and his only group is cvs.
I "chrooted" the user "ben" accessing only the cvs functionality by not allowing to access the server via ssh with password, only by using a public key which is added in his home directory on the server in file authorized_keys2.

the contect of authorized_keys2 is as follows:

```
no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="/usr/bin/cvs server" ssh-rsa [public_key_content] rsa-key
```

Connecting to the server works pretty fine. Eclipse asks for the passphrase for the private key to connect to the server. Authentication works and eclipse is able to run cvs commands.

But when importing my project by using Team->Share Project. I get the error:

```
The server reported an error: Permission denied
projectname: cvs server: cannot open /priv/cvs/CVSROOT/config: Permission denied
projectname: Cannot access /priv/cvs/CVSROOT
```

The access right for the cvs root (/priv/cvs/) is set to 770. Which means that the owner, which is cvs and the group participants of the group cvs are allowed to read and write.

Why do i get Permission denied?

When i set the folder to 777, which means read/write to ALL, then it works. But i dont want that. I only want cvs users read/write to this folder?
Is there something i misunderstood about access rules?

One thing i forgot:
All files and directory in /priv/cvs are chmodded to cvs:cvs and all folders in /priv/cvs/ have been chmodded to 775 (read by all, write by owner/group).

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is probably using an unpriviledged user to access the server. Check the server logs for the failed access attempts, and use the CVS Repository view in Eclipse to define access tot he repository.

Team/Share is not the correct way to do an initial checkout from CVS in Eclipse; it is intended for Eclipse to grab CVS information from existing/working project directories.

Comment: In eclipse the user is set to "ben", same username like the one on server with the authorized_keys2 thing. And i was always importing new projects that way. But this time its on another server and i dont see any difference. I tried exploring the repository using the CVS Repository Explorer in Eclipse, but still getting same error. :-(

Comment: One more thing. I logged in as ben and cvs using the su command as root. I was able to print the content of the config file and list all files in CVSROOT. But trying it via Eclipse ends up in error above. What the heck?

Comment: Crap!! I had to restart eclipse so it reprompts for passphrase used by private key. Now its working. Even if its working now, im totally confused. No idea what the problem was.

Comment: Eclipse CVS works best with the embedded (Java) CVS client implementation, because it doesn't get "contaminated" by the OS context. The setting is under Windows/Preferences/Team/SSH. Did you check the server logs?